# NavigationEnd is fired before the data are resolved for next page Angular

Tags: angular

Im doing something like this

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
  if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
    return;
  }
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

because I want to scroll to the top of the page every time user navigates. The interesting part is `NavigationEnd` is triggered **before** data for next page are resolved. So it first scrolls to the top (on a same page), than wait for server (100ms or so) and than shows the new page. Which is really weird. The documentation speaks of `NavigationEnd` as `An event triggered when navigation ends successfully.` Shouldn't NavigationEnd be very last thing after the next page is ready to be displayed?

https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events

So does anyone knows what I should use instead?

Comment: where are you putting this code?  in which component, in the current component or in the target component where you will be redirected?

Comment: This code is from app.component.ts

Comment: You ever got a working solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the topic is kinda of old, but since Angular 6.x you can use :

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'})
```

In your case, you might want to set it to 'top'. Other extra options can be found at https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions

From my understanding, NavigationEnd is triggered before the redirect actually happens. It holds the url requested and the final url (urlAfterRedirects), providing the information about how the request has been handled by your application.

Answer (score 0):

Actually under the hood it fires couple of NavigationEnd events, so you need to specify exact `url` you need like this

`!(val instanceof NavigationEnd && val.url !== '/home')`

our use different strategy. If you `log` this events you will see that it gives a lot of events before getting your page.

Comment: I have this code in app.component.ts so, it lives through the whole lifecycle of app. And when I log `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` it is there just once per navigation action.